# Select speaker output with headphones inserted (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

I just installed ubuntu 13.04 on my desktop machine and have a problem with speakers and headphones. Speakers as well as headphones are working independently, but not together. Every time I plug my headphones into my front audio jack ubuntu switches to the headphone output. 
When I reselect the speakers output in the settings->sound menu, nothing happens. The headphones still play. To me, it seems that ubuntu routes the sound output to headphones if they are inserted regardless whether they are selected (the "test-function" inside the sound settings plays regardless of output selection both times headphones, but not if I select the digital output port S/PDIF).
I installed gnome-alsamixer, but cannot start it, since it gives me a seg fault.

Any ideas / suggestions?